# Getting "The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-1033" when trying to create a scratch org?

Tags: salesforce

When I try and create a scratch org as follows...

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a myscratchorg
```

I am getting following error :

```
The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-1033
```

Sample Scratch Org Definition

```
{
  "orgName": "<Org name here>",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": []
}
```

Tried rerunning the Builds.

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385376/why-am-i-getting-the-request-to-create-a-scratch-org-failed-with-error-code-c) and the solution for you would be to add the below to your config file. This will put you on the upcoming release, assuming that your DevHub is already upgraded to that release.

```
{ 
  ...
 "release": "preview"
  ...
}
```

if your DevHub is not on your release, replace `"preview"` with `"previous"`